# Zend Framework return JSON to ajax GET Request without Doctype HTML

Tags: json, jquery, zend-framework

I am  trying to return a JSON Object to an AJAX request via GET on an specific Action.

This is my Action triggered via the GET-Request:

```
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout(); 
    $Mapper = new Application_Model_Mapper();
    $result = $Mapper->findById($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

   echo $this->_helper->json($result);
```

The Response is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

`[{"foo":"bar", ... }]`

Through the Doctype tag, I can't process the JSON data correctly as it is not recognized as a JSON object.

I tried to remove  the Doctype tag with not rendering the view and disabling layout in the Action but it is still there. Any thoughts on removing them properly from the response?

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch

Comment: @danronmoon Thanks, used the ajaxContext helper, but the HTML Markup is still there...

Comment: How are you adding the doctype?  Make sure you are using the view helper (Zend_View_Helper_Doctype on ZF1) in your bootstrap file.

Comment: @danronmoon I don't even set the doctype in the bootstrap file, I don't get how it is set there.

Comment: Got it! It was a lost <!doctype html> tag in the public/index.php.